# Identifying the first zero character in a numerical value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have numerical values formatted e.g `"00125250058"`
I want to identify the first 3 character including the zero. Using `Left`... Excel excludes the `00` and start from e.g. `125` when I want `001`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your number first to text with `TEXT(A1, "00000000000"`) (`"0...0"` is the format of your number) and then apply left to it

`LEFT(TEXT(A1,"00000000000"),3)`

Comment: did that, but since I need the 3 as numeric had to reformat that to numbers.